# Check how many lines will a <p> tag occupy

Tags: javascript, html

I was wandering, is there a way to check how many lines will a text in a `<p>` tag occupy after beeng wrapped? I know the width & height of `<div>` that contains this `<p>`.

This question came up when I was trying to cut a text if it's more then 3 lines long, and make it expandable later. I know I can achieve this by cutting the text with fixed length (average symbol count in a line).  But I was just wandering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't actually need to know how many pixels the text is long if you use relative units for font-size, line-height and height: see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6WRsg/

I set a `line-height: 1.3` and `height: 3.9em /* (1.3 * 3 lines) */`; so no matter what the font-size is, you always display at most three lines of text.

When you need to show all the content just switch programmatically (via javascript) the height to `auto`

Answer (score 1):

You could place the para temporarily miles outside the visible page with position:absolute, left:-2000px and then check its offsetHeight to get an idea of how many lines it will have.  Not sure how you'd find exact line breaks tho.