# Split a text into two lines

Tags: css

Is there a way to force a part of a text to display on a new line with CSS?

So when the HTML looks like this:

```
<p>Hello, my name is John.</p>
```

The result will be:

> Hello,
>
> my name is John.

The HTML is generated dynamically, so I cannot change it.

Comment: No, use two elements. Can try wrapping with JS

Comment: Change your html to `<p>Hello,<br> my name is John.</p>`

Comment: @StavrosAngelis I know how to do it with HTML but that was not the question.

Comment: You can use js to insert `br`

Comment: Css doesn't support what you want to do. Your only option is to split the string with javascript in the coma character and add a break line afterwards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap a text within only two lines inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989546/wrap-a-text-within-only-two-lines-inside-div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
p::before {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 3.6em);
  height: 1em;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, my name is John.</p>
```

Please note that this is rather fidgety: the `3.6em` is somewhere in between the width of `"Hello,"` and the width of `"Hello, my"`. So this depends on the font as well as the word(s) you need it to break after. I had to experiment a bit with different fonts to find a good average size.

Comment: OK. But please see the note I added just now (which I should have added yesterday).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you cannot split a text without writing code in between your texts.

Follow this link which provides a good solution.

[How to give line-break from css, without using <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Answer (score 0):

But this does not even consider where to split the lines automatically. If you want something more automated, you need to use php or javascript.

Here is an example from another link:
[SPLIT HTML INTO different lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915469/how-to-split-an-html-paragraph-up-into-its-lines-of-text-with-javascript)

Check and let me know if it helps you.

Thanks
S

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways how to do it.

**First** is using the `<br>` element of HTML

```
<p>Hello,<br> my name is John.</p>
```

**Second** is to put both of it in `<p>` tag

```
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>my name is John.</p>
```

**Third** is by putting both of it in `<p>` tag with css attribute and value `clear:both` - this is to make sure that no element will be floated in left or right

Try the codes below and hope it helps you.

```css
p {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>my name is John.</p>
```

All of it will output

> Hello,
>
> my name is John.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned in my question, I cannot change the HTML. I am looking for a CSS solution or similar.

Comment: @Reza really? are you using a template or somewhat a drag and drop tool?

Comment: Nope, I am using Drupal. I need it for one of the menu items.

Answer (score -4):

```
<p>Hello, <br>my name is John.</p>
```

or just put another `<p></p>` tags

```
<p>Hello, </p>&nbsp;<p>my name is John.</p>
```

Comment: Uhm ... Really?